# One Night Ultimate Werewolf: If your card is moved, whose team are you on?

Tags: werewolf, one-night-werewolf

I've been playing One Night Ultimate Werewolf (ONUW) for a few years, and I'm afraid we've been doing it wrong.

I play so that if you're a Werewolf at the start of the game, you stay on the Werewolf team even if your card is moved. Thus, if you discover your card was swapped with a Villager, for instance, you would want to convince people to vote for your card so that a villager is killed and you (the Werewolf) wins. Is this wrong?

Comment: Note that you also can't look at your role card after the night phase ends. So in general, you won't know if your roll was switched. (Someone could say that they switched your card, but you don't know if you can believe them).

Comment: What would be the point of switching role cards, if that were the case?

Comment: Well, the way we played it, the trouble was we didn't know where the Werewolf cards wound up, so if a Werewolf discovered that their card was moved, they would try to make everyone vote for their new card, which was a villager, to win the game.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is very wrong.

The rules are clear that you act whatever you *had*, you are whatever you *have*:

> After the night phase, **your role is the card that is currently in front of you**, which may be different than your original role.

with emphasis added

Comment: Thank you for that clarification! I am terrible at reading instructions XD

Answer (score 6):

You are the role/side of the card that you end up with at the end of the game once it is revealed. I have listed the rules for the robber as an example.

In your example if you are able to discover your card is now a villager because of information gained from other players you would want to sell out a werewolf so they get killed and the villagers win because you would now win with them.

[Robber Rules](https://www.fgbradleys.com/rules/rules2/OneNightUltimateWerewolf-rules.pdf)

> At night, the Robber may choose
>   to rob a card from another player
>   and place his Robber card where
>   the other card was. Then the
>   Robber looks at his new card. The
>   player who receives the Robber
>   card is on the village team.
>   The Robber is on the
>   team of the card he takes, however, he does not do
>   the action of his new role at night.